# Como implementar un framework diferente a Boostrap en una aplicacion de ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

La idea es poder implementar otro framework frontend como Materialize, Semantic-UI, UI-Kit o foundation en una App de ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Hola J. Vilches, te invito a que conozcas como funciona esta comunidad leyendo esta [presentación](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). Esta pregunta podría ser cerrada ya que no se ajusta a los estándares de calidad del sitio. En respuesta a tu pregunta, cualquier framework se usa de la misma manera, se enlazan las hojas de estilo y los guiones de javascript.

Comment: la forma de implementar no tiene que ver con asp.net mvc, estas librerias que encionas aplican sobre el html y css, es en el codigo de la view donde definas el tag script y link para referencia el .js y .css que necesites y eso es todo, despues el resto es entender como se sua la libreria en particular

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio @J.Vilches. Veo que muchas de tus preguntas son demasiado amplias. Te recomiendo que delimites el alcance de tus preguntas, intentes resolver algo por tu cuenta y cuando tengas dificultades brindes detalles sobre qué te dificulta y qué sucede.